# Do iOS Safari and/or Microsoft Edge support push notifications?

Tags: ios, safari, notifications, push, microsoft-edge

From the research I've done, I cannot find any concrete answers to this question. The desktop version of Safari has supported this functionality for some time, but does the iOS version also natively support pushing notifications from websites? If not is there an alternative solution?

I also cannot find anything on Microsoft Edge supporting this function either. I feel like I read that at one point in time, but I'm having a hard time finding anything now.

Comment: I don't think Apple supports push notification in iOS Safari as of now. According to their doc, currently it is only supported on OS X 10.9 or above.  
However I will also do some research on  my part and will let you know if I come across any alternative.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html

Comment: Hi J.p. Hechter, if my answer was helpful it would be great if you could flag my answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Edge does not currently support notifications, although it is currently under consideration with 550 votes on User Voice.

You can find the current status on [status.modern.ie.](https://status.modern.ie/pushapi?term=push)

Answer (score 1):

**Support for Microsoft Edge will come very soon**, since on *Feb 3, 2016* [Microsoft announced](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263693-push-api):

> The Push API is on the backlog with a priority of high.

For iOS currently there are no official plans.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS don't support push notifications. If you need services to send push notifications to your phone without making an app/etc. You could always use Pushover/Pushbullet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display push notifications from your web application on Windows 10 you might consider building a hosted web app and distribute it through the store. This will give you the opportunity to send system push notifications. See http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/06/project-westminster-in-a-nutshell/ for an introducation. The sample on that page demonstrates the use of push notifications from a web app:

```
if (typeof Windows !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof Windows.UI !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof Windows.UI.Notifications !== 'undefined') {
      //Call Windows.UI.Notifications
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with push notifications is there are still a lot of people on older Firefox and Chrome Browsers, Internet Explorer may never be supported, Safari will be based around Apple's own protocols, and so as exciting as web browser push is - it can only be part of the solution.

I am starting to code up notifications via Amazon Web Services SNS, and if it goes well I will circle back.  They don't yet support the Chrome/Firefox notifications, but as Amazon want this for internal use I think there is a good chance it will happen (or I can create a simple Lambda function for this if needed).

Currently Amazon support:

You send push notification messages to both mobile devices and desktops using one of the following supported push notification services:

- Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)
- Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for both iOS and Mac OS X
- Baidu Cloud Push (Baidu)
- Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)
- Microsoft Push Notification Service for Windows Phone (MPNS)
- Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)

Note that does include iOS and OSX, and the Windows Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the most recent Windows Insider Preview release (build 14.14342), Web Notifications are enabled by default in **Microsoft Edge** on Windows 10 PCs and tablets. (since may 16, 2016)